Can SQL Server with Entra Authentication accept pre-Windows 2000 identifiers?
I have a SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machine joined to a Microsoft Entra Domain Services instance that has Enable Microsoft Entra authentication for SQL Server on Azure VMs enabled.
I have a user in Entra ID: user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com.
I have created a SQL Server LOGIN for that user by running:
CREATE LOGIN [user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER

This allows me to authenticate to SQL Server via SSMS using the Microsoft Entra options:

However, an application I wish to deploy only offers Windows Authentication or Native SQL Authentication.
I don't believe that SQL Server Authentication can be mapped to an Entra user.
Using Windows Authentication attempts to authenticate using the pre-Windows 2000 identifier of mydomain\user rather than the UPN user@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com and results in an error
as the user cannot be found.
I am unable to create a SQL Login using the pre-Windows 2000 identifier as the name doesn't appear to allow for backslashes:
CREATE LOGIN [mydomain\user] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER


Msg 15006, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
'mydomain\user' is not a valid name because it contains invalid characters.

As per the title question, can SQL Server with Entra Authentication be configured to accept pre-Windows 2000 identifiers?
If that is not possible I believe my only options are to:

Abandon Entra and maintain a full AD instance on a VM, resorting back to Windows Authentication
Abandon Entra and maintain native SQL logins for all users of my service
Convince the vendor of the application I am deploying to allow for Entra / UPN style authentication


That's not a pre-Windows 2000 identifier, it's a domain account used incorrectly.  It's identical to user@full.domain.whatever. You don't add Windows logins with FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER. If the Azure VM is in the same Azure AD domain, adding the Windows login should work.

Abandon Entra and maintain a full AD instance on a VM a better option would be to add your SQL VM to the same (ie the customer's) domain.

"Entra Domain Services" is Microsoft-managed managed AD.  It's different from the main Entra ID/AAD.  So creating and adding domain users should already work.  Just create user [mydomain\username] from windows.

Thanks all, I'd completely forgotten the difference between Entra ID and Entra Domain Services, the latter allowing me to use "standard" concepts. Adding the LOGIN as you both described directly as a WINDOWS user obviously worked.

If you found the solution, please add it as answer to help other community members.
